# how can the audio going to play if the code given is correct on js

Tags: javascript, html

i am currently practicing my html and js skills and i have this code which is when i click the unlock button the audio will automatically play but the problem is even the unlock code is wrong the audio will still play this is my html on the button and on the audio

the audio tag:

```
<audio id="music" src="bgmusic.mp3" controls hidden loop></audio>
```

the button tag:

```
<button id="unlock" class="round pink"  onclick="playAudio()">
                    Unlock

                </button>
```

and here's my current js for the onlick event on the button

```
                    var x = 
                    document.getElementById("music");

                    function playAudio() {
                        x.play();
                    }
```

that is my current syntax but what i want to happen is when the audio will only play if i enter the correct code

and here's the js function for the unlock code functionality:

```
 var number = 0;

      $('#unlock').on('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();

            $('#textMachine').css('display', 'inline-block');
            var code = '';
            $.each($('.code'), function(i, v) {
                code += $(v).val();
            });


            if(code == '30')
            {
                // success
                var machine = $('#textMachine').slotMachine({
                    active: 0,
                    delay: 500,
                    randomize : function(activeElementIndex){
                        return 3;
                    }
                });

                machine.setRandomize(3);

                machine.shuffle(5, function(){
                    answerCorrect();
                });
            } else {


                if(number == 3) { number = 0; }

                // fail
                var machine = $('#textMachine').slotMachine({
                    active: 1,
                    delay: 500,
                    randomize : function(activeElementIndex){
                        return number;
                    }
                });


                machine.shuffle(5, function(){
                    number++;
                });
            }
            
      });

      var answerCorrect = function() {
            $('.login-form').fadeOut();
            $('.congratulation-text').fadeIn();
            $('.success-area').css('display','block');
            


      };


  })();
```

Answer (score 0):

well actually you can do this

```js
function playSound () {
   var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
   audio.play();
}
```

and you can call it on your button or your function